# Is Christmas a good day to play poker?

Tags: casino

I have always thought the games seemed kind of tight and most of the players a little grumpy. Playing or not have a merry Christmas.

Comment: Jon - Thanks for the good wishes and I hope you also have a great  holiday.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a really bad question for this site; you're really asking nothing. And please stop with the insults, it's totally inappropiate.

Comment: @RaduMurzea While it is certainly not the greatest question, it is OK, Xmas is a strange day to play, things are different.

Comment: @JimBeam Re: your deleted comments... http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19245747#19245747